# Keep away from your phone or keep away your phone?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm trying to transmit this message, but I'm not sure what is the correct way to do so. In short words I'm trying to give an order.

Comment: It would help if you would explain what you are trying to say.  Do you mean "Stay far away from your phone" or "Make sure that your phone stays put away"?

Answer (score 2):

*Keep (or **stay**) away from your phone* would be the proper way to order someone. Both sentences have an implied *you* in front of them. *You* keep away from your phone and *You* keep away your phone. But in the second sentence you are implying that the person should keep their phone away, rather than saying they should keep away from their phone. Usually you aren't ordering someone to keep their phone away from them, but rather are ordering them to keep away from their phone.

Comment: But _keep away your phone_ would be very odd wording even in that case: _keep your phone away_ would be **much** more natural.

Comment: I agree. I hardly ever hear anyway phrase it the other way.

Comment: Perhaps ordering is better than commanding? Anyway, I agree with the idea.

Comment: I agree. I replaced command with order.

Answer (score 2):

"Keep away from your phone" is grammatical, but not very natural. A better way to say this would be "Stay away from your phone" -- meaning "keep a large physical distance between you and your phone". This is a strange thing to ask someone to do, though (unless you think the phone will explode).

"Keep away your phone" is not grammatical. To *keep something away* means that **it is trying to approach you** but you prevent it from approaching you. "Making loud noises will **keep bears away**." "An apple a day **keeps the doctor away**." But a phone is not alive or animate, so it cannot try to approach you.

To convey the meaning you want, I would say "Keep your phones **put away**". This means "it is OK to have your phone *near* you, but it must stay in your pocket or handbag or desk". (I suppose you could say "keep your phone away", but it is less natural.) You could also say "Keep **off** your phones". This would suggest that it might be OK to take your phone out, but you should not actually *use* it.

Comment: I think it's six of one, half a dozen of the other. Keep away from those cookies,  young man. Stay away from those cookies, young man. Same thing.